# CoreData Confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, uitableview

I am starting out with CoreData and have managed to incorporate it into my project. I did this by making a new project with CoreData included and based all the code of what I am given there, helping me understand it a little.

Now the new project lets me add a time stamp and then view the details of that. However what I want o achieve uses multiple attributes in my entity and this has gotten me a little stumped as to how to handle them.

What I want to achieve: The user sees a tableview with each object represented by the 'firstName' and 'lastName' attributes. So they see a list of people. Then when selecting a person, it will bring up a new view (UINavigationController being used) in which further attributes can be seen and altered, such as 'gender' and 'age' as examples.

I am a little stumped; Ray Wenderlich's introduction to CoreData has helped, but doesn't quite guide me in the right direction.

Comment: So as to not be redundant here, how far have you gotten so far with this. Have you created your core data model? If so have you generated your person class to match the core data model (if you haven't xcode does this for you and I can explain how). Finally have you created your first tableview to show the first name and last name of people yet?

Comment: Well the first thing I have been racking been brain about it how can I first goth a new view save some text values the user enters (the first and last name) and then load it in? As it needs to be saved before it can be loaded into a table. The code apple produces is that required? Or are there simpler ways to achieving this as another thought.

Comment: As long as implement your `UITableView` correctly using a `NSFetchedResultsController` then whenever or wherever in your program you create or modify a Person object, when you save the `NSManagedObjectContext` the changes will be reflected in the table automatically. This is because the `NSFetchedResultsController` is notified of all changes to the underlying data (coredata) and will update the tableview accordingly (provided you set it up correctly and this is mostly copying and pasting from the `NSFetchedResultsController` code reference page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you a registered iPhone developer? You should check out Apple's sample code. The CoreDataBooks project does exactly this. Here's a [link.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405) I used this to set up my own Core Data project recently.

They also are extremely efficient in handling everything, including adding, editing, and deleting objects. You should probably just edit this project, if all you want to do is what you described in the question.

Comment: This source code looks, magical. Good things could come from this, I'll give it a shot now. (It does just about exactly what I want to achieve.) I'll report back on my attempt to integrate.

Comment: Good luck, it was very helpful for me as well.

Comment: Correction. This code 'is' magical. Thanks for drawing my attention to it! Got it working.